# Powershell remoting not working on same machine with hostname

Tags: powershell, http, iis, winrm, winrs

Powershell Remoting failed with local server hostname, whereas works with remote server hostname. I am getting this error with local server hostname:

> The WInRM client sent a request to an http server and got a response
>   saying the requested http url was not available.

`Winrs -r:http://servername:5985 "dir"` not working and throws same error.

I tried `winrm qc`, `Enable-PSRemoting`, WinRM listener listening ipv6, GPO enabled with  * on both ipv6 and ipv4 . Nothing worked

Comment: check the result of "winrm quickconfig"